# Comment syntax ambiguity under GAS ARM target

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

The GNU GAS documentation appears to fail to properly define certain syntax features for the ARM target, so I'm having difficulty writing even simple assembly.

Two such examples:

- The [ARM Compiler Migration and Compatibility Guide Version 6.02](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0742/c/migrating-arm-syntax-assembly-code-to-gnu-syntax/comments) states that, as well as multi-line comments, under GNU syntax:

  > The `//` marker identifies the remainder of a line as a comment:
  >
  > `MOV R0,#16    // Load R0 with 16`

  which appears to conflict with the [Using as](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars) guide, which states:

  > The presence of a ‘@’ anywhere on a line indicates the start of a comment that extends to the end of that line.
- The issue of implicit shifts in instructions is only addressed in passing in the Arm documentation, and only gives the failing case:

  > GNU syntax assembly expects immediate values to be presented as encoded. The instruction `MOVK x1, #0x40000` results in the following message: `error: immediate must be an integer in range [0, 65535].`

  What exactly is meant by "encoded"? Am I to assume that the `LSL` syntax is supported identically under GNU? It doesn't appear to be addressed in GAS documentation.

Is there somewhere I can find concrete and complete syntax definition for GAS + ARM target?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GAS supports both `//` comments and `@` comments itself, even without using the C preprocessor to handle C/C++-style comments.

(Call your file `foo.S` with a capital S and `gcc -c foo.S` will run it through CPP first, so you can use `#define` and `#if 0` and stuff like that.)

"Encoded" means representable in machine code.  e.g. `MOVK x1, #0x40000` isn't a *syntax* error, it's an error at a later stage than parsing because there's no way to represent it that specific number in machine code with that opcode.  But `mov x1, #0x40000` is fine because the assembler can pick a bit-range encoding for `orr`-immediate with `xzr`.  Note that that's AArch64, which uses different machine code than ARM.

**GAS ARM syntax is the same as what official ARM manuals document.**  *Directives* are different than Keil's ARMasm, but the syntax of instruction lines is (mostly?) identical.  @old_timer says there are or were some differences with `mrc` and `mcr` syntax, but for the most part GAS aims to be compatible with standard ARM syntax.

**See the GAS manual's [ARM Dependent Features](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dDependent.html#ARM_002dDependent) chapter, including a section on Syntax.**

(Note that ARM has a couple different syntax modes, "unified" vs. the older one that used different syntax for ARM vs. Thumb mode.  Usually you want `.syntax unified`)

You can always look at GCC C compiler output for examples (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/z/Tk_jrD), although for a specific case you'd have to write a C function where GCC will use the instruction or addressing mode you're interested in.  GCC uses GAS directives.

Comment: Hi thanks. I didn't realise .S enabled CPP preprocessing - that's neat. So am I right to assume that I can write `STR R0, [R3, R2, LSL #2]` under GAS? It's the exact permitted syntax that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere that I'm struggling with. Is GAS largely accommodating of official ARM syntax, then?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut - that assembles fine for me with `arm-none-eabi-as`, and `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d` disassembles the `e7830102` result back into that instruction.  Other than directives, ARM GAS syntax matches ARMasm in general.  I don't know of any exceptions.

Comment: gas arm assembly language is very much not the same as the arm manuals as this question clearly indicates.  assembly language is defined by the assembler not the target, gnu tends to make their's incompatible with the vendors tools (unless that chose to use gnu as their primary tool).  you need to read the gnu documentation.  Note that if you use the compiler to assemble stuff (why? why? why?) then that is a whole new syntax added on the top because it is now C if you use gcc in front of gnu assembly language.  Further confusing things.

Comment: @old_timer: I said *directives* are different.  Can you give an example of a real  *instruction* mnemonic + operands that assembles differently (or not at all) between GAS vs. Keil, when they're both in unified syntax mode?

Comment: I am talking more generic.  the mrc, mcr used to be incompatible between arm and gas.  stm and ldm have incompatibilities (push/pop) as the SO question the other day showed.  I think the mrc/mcr has been fixed since then.  I imagine there are others.

Comment: the point is to not make general statements like that implying that assemblers conform to the same language/syntax, because they dont.  despite this being a search for external documentation (And thus worth closing not answering) the correct documentation for the gnu tools is from gnu.  granted someone from arm does/did work on gnu stuff and in places the only documentation may be the source code which is extra fun to read coming from gnu.

Comment: @old_timer: I did say "AFAIK" as a disclaimer because the broad strokes are the same, e.g. the OP wasn't sure that `STR R0, [R3, R2, LSL #2]` would do the same thing under GAS.  Updated that based on your comments, thanks.

Comment: the pop just now worked, will have to look at that question from the other day again

Comment: @old_timer: `pop  {r0-r4}` assembles fine, you just can't omit the space between the mnemonic and operands.  But good point about the GAS manual, also linked that.

Comment: fair enough I just saw the bold type and reacted to that...I dont have current copies of any of the arm tools, I think there are evals probably available but I stick to gnu/llvm these days.  so I cant go back and forth between them. just versions of binutils/gnu and clang with and without unified syntax

Comment: I struggled with some floating point syntax a couple of years ago, dont remember the details now.  switched from the newer syntax to the older (same machine code, new neon or whatever syntax) and that is how I got past that.  unified syntax makes it harder to get the non-thumb2 instruction you are after as the tool seems to try more to get it to work than do what you asked, perhaps there is a directive/command line argument for that, dont replace my instruction...

Comment: psuedo instructions like ldr r0,=blah dont behave the same on all assemblers, gas is quite flexible and makes it just work be it a mov, mvn, or pc relative ldr.  But there was a question where it wasnt working for someone using something not-gnu, dont remember which assembler that was.  but that is a pseudo instruction not the syntax from the arm arm.

Comment: and you clarified unified syntax, for the longest time before unified syntax and still without the thumb instructions being subs r0,#1  gas rejects it if the s is there, but it generates the subs instruction and the disassembler shows it as subs.  with unified syntax you need the s there to get it to generate the instruction you want.

Comment: @old_timer After facing several question closure threats over reasonable and researched assembly Qs, I often question the utility and attitude of this site. This is not merely a request for docs, as you've said yourself sometimes the only docs are the source itself. The ARM specific section of the gas docs almost might at well not be there. Most sections are incomplete and if there are such incompatibilities between ARMasm and ARM GAS, the syntax for ARM specific features should be precisely documented.

Comment: While I appreciate the "no guarantee" nature of OSS, for the main free assembler for a target to be "this works sometimes because of compatibility but I only know this because Bob wrote the patch" seriously detracts from the platform.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut: agreed; it's unfortunate that GAS instruction syntax details aren't better documented for all targets.  For ARM, there really only is one syntax, the one defined by ARM, and it makes sense that GAS wouldn't bother to re-document all of that.  I don't do a lot of ARM stuff (I mostly do x86) so I haven't run into the syntax differences for `mrc` or `mcr` that old_timer mentioned.  He has a lot of ARM experience so I'm inclined to believe him, unless that was also an incompatibility bug that's been fixed.  IDK if the situation is as bleak as he describes.